# Boolean Test on records of ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a large number of records in Cassandra database, I want to tag records based on some boolean rules (by applying Elastic Search Boolean Rules). Below are the steps I am following to achieve this.

1. Reading record from Cassandra Database one by one
2. Putting it (single record) to the Elastic Search Server
3. Then applying boolean count on the posted record
4. If count > 0 then I tag Cassandra record that boolean is matched
5. Delete the record that is posted to the Elastic Search
6. And then repeat above steps for next record

Above steps are working, but the process is very too slow and sometimes it gives wrong result if apply put and count query consecutively. And I have to call 2 API calls for to tag one record.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there any way to post body content and boolean query together to Elastic Search to check if boolean is matching or not?
2. Is there any other way to test boolean rules on the data locally without posting to Elastic Search? (Rules must be compatible as of ES)
3. Is there any way to in Elastic Search to know if posted data is successfully saved and indexed so that we can apply boolean query immediately?
4. I heard of Lucene engine, is Lucene engine used internally by Elastic Search, if yes then is it possible to setup Lucene engine only for boolean test?

I am using **nodejs** to do all these things, also solution must be applied for multilingual data. Thanks.

Comment: What is this boolean rule? It does sound like you need [percolator functionality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need [multi percolate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-percolate.html#_multi_percolate_api) + bulk update for cassandra